# Adding Google accounts to Cloud Identity Groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-identity, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I have Google identity with a domain `example.com` and have created a group, say `my-admins@example.com`. I can create users `a-user@example.com` and say `another-user@example.com` and add them to group `my-admins@example.com`.

I have a Google Cloud organization example.com and have successfully added `my-admins@example.com` and assigned it the roles I want (e.g Organization Admins).

It's possible for me to add google accounts, e.g `googleaccount123@gmail.com` as principals to my organization and assign them roles, but I can't seem to add them to the `my-admins@example.com` group.

Are my Google identity groups always scoped to users with the same domain? If so how do I get to a place where I can manage a mixed group of example users and google accounts?

Comment: What is the error? Yes, you can add external identities to a group. Check which group type you are modifying.

Comment: Please update your question with the details how you're trying to add a member to a group and what error message you're getting. When you go to group details can you add any members ? It's possible that there's an [organization policy that blocks adding external members](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains). You can add screenshots if possible too.

Answer (score 2):

I've realized the issue is that there is a group attribute allowing/denying adding members from outside of the organization.

Comment: Please update your solution with more details so other community members can benefit from that :)